# Prevent line breaks in wkhtmltopdf generated pdf

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, line-breaks

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` to generate pdf files from html templates. Rest of stack is `Flask` with `Jinja2` and `pdfkit` as wrapper around `wkhtmltopdf`.

I need to generate some files containg code. There are few long lines there, which have to break, to fit page's width. `wkhtmltopdf` is inserting `\n` (I think) at the end of each line.

I want to have linebrakes without newline characters, to allow users to select whole code (few lines) and copy-paste it as one line. Is it possible? How to achieve it?

Eg:
`<some-element attribute-number-one="having-very-long&boring-value" another-attribute="with-no-meaning-whatsoever"></some-element>`

Try copy-paste code above. It should be pasted as one line, even though it's displayed as few lines. I want to achieve the same effect in `wkhtmltopdf`-generated pdf files.

Comment: Read **10.6 Logical Structure** and **10.7 Tagged PDF** in Adobe's *PDF Reference, version 1.7*  (or ISO 32000-1, but that's much drier) for the exact phrases and terminology to look for in wkhtmltopdf's documentation.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I'm facing the same challenge.

Comment: @LucasHenrique unfortunately I did not, sorry.